# Blog post Links leading to home page

Tags: urls, homepage, blog, blog-page

I have a Wordpress site with a paid theme but I seem to have a problem with the blog posts. When I create a blogpost, the blog post title and read more links appears in the blog menu item I have. But when the link is clicked, the website goes to home page instead of the blog post. What could be the issue? Any idea where to start trouble shooting?

Comment: You should ask the theme developers, even more, if it's a paid theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Delete you .htaccess file in root
2. Reset your permalink structure
3. If have access to the theme file make sure your blog title link refers to    the_permalink() as destination.
4. you might have open anchor tag from the logo which developer forgot to close.See page source or inspect it.
5. Share the code in your loop.